# Casting to a base class using generics

Tags: c#, generics

I seem to have some trouble understanding generics in c#.

Basically i have a base class called `ConfigWorker` and a bunch of sub classes which should all use their own config class deriving from `BaseConfig`.

The ConfigWorker class i want to use should be determined dynamically during runtime given the name of the class as a parameter.

I can instantiate the sub class given it's name, but no matter what i try, i can't get the casting to a sensible base class to work.

Here's my code:

```
namespace DocumentHandler
{

    public class BaseConfig
    {
    }

    public class ConfigWorker<T> where T : BaseConfig
    {
        public virtual void Work(T options)
        {

        }

    }

    public class Worker1 : ConfigWorker<Worker1.Config>
    {
        public class Config : BaseConfig
        {
            public string test = "";
        }

        public override void Work(Config options)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }

    public class Worker2 : ConfigWorker<Worker2.Config>
    {
        public class Config : BaseConfig
        {
            public string test = "";
        }

        public override void Work(Config options)
        {
            //do something else
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public static BaseConfig config; 

        public static void test()
        {
            (Activator
                .CreateInstance(Type.GetType("DocumentHandler.Worker2")) 
                as ConfigWorker<BaseConfig>)
            .Work(config);
        }
    }
}
```

The crucial line is

```
(Activator
    .CreateInstance(Type.GetType("DocumentHandler.Worker2")) 
    as ConfigWorker<BaseConfig>)
.Work(config);
```

The casting to `ConfigWorker<BaseConfig>` returns null, as the cast can not be performed.

Trying to simply cast to `ConfigWorker` does not compile as the type parameter is missing.

Anything else i can try? `CreateInstance` obviously just returns an object and i need to cast that to be able to call the `Work` method

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just because two types `T1` and `T2` have a particular inheritance relationship, that does *not* mean that a generic type parameterized with those types (`G<T1>` and `G<T2>`) exhibits the same inheritance relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An instance of Worker2 is not a `ConfigWorker<BaseConfig>`! It's a `ConfigWorker<Worker2.Config>`. These are two totally different types. Generic classes are invariant. Only interfaces and delegates can be co- or contra-variant.

In your example, `ConfigWorker` is even *contra-variant* in `T`, meaning you use `T` as the type of an *input* parameter to a method. So what you try is actually dangerous.

Imagine your line would work: you get an variable of type `ConfigWorker<BaseConfig>`, so you could rely on this instance having a method `Work()` which takes a `BaseConfig` (or something derived from it) as argument. So nothing could stop you from calling it like

```
worker.Work(new Worker1.Config());
```

Compiles fine. But wait a moment! Didn't your line state that `worker` is a `Worker2`? `Worker2` instances can only handle `Worker2.Config` arguments!
You completely loose type safety this way (well, you would if it was allowed).

There is a flaw in your class design.

Comment: Hi René, thank you for the good explanation. I understand what you are saying. Coming from a Java background, where generics work quite differently, i find it hard to understand that something like this seems to be impossible in C#. I am aware of the fact that i would loose type safety and that one may consider this to be dangerous. In my specific case i would ensure that the type of the parameter matches the types needed for the instantiated sub class. I'm wondering if it's possible to circumvent type checking in that case to make something like this work.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a good problem that factory pattern has good good solution for.
Here is a simplified solution

```
 namespace DocumentHandler
{

    public interface IBaseConfig
    {
    }

    public class ConfiManager : IBaseConfig
{

}

    public abstract class WorkerFactory
    {

        private readonly IBaseConfig _config;

        protected WorkerFactory(IBaseConfig config)
        {
            this._config = config;
        }

        public virtual void Work()
        {

        }





    }

    public class Worker1 : WorkerFactory
{
    private readonly IBaseConfig _config;

    public Worker1(IBaseConfig config):base(config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

            public string test = "";


        public override void Work()
        {
            //do something
        }
    }

    public class Worker2 : WorkerFactory
{
    private readonly IBaseConfig _config;

            public string test = "";

            public Worker2(IBaseConfig config):base(config)
            {
                this._config = config;
            }


            public override void Work()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public static IBaseConfig config = new ConfiManager();

        public static void test()
        {
            WorkerFactory worker =
                (Worker2) Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("DocumentHandler.Worker2"), config);

            worker.Work();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi codein, thanks for the solution. So i guess i can make it work by not using the specific config class as a parameter to the Work method, but always sticking to the base class and then manually casting to the derived config class inside the methods body.

Comment: According to your statement "The ConfigWorker class i want to use should be determined dynamically during runtime given the name of the class as a parameter.", When you determine the worker class, it's quite simple to instantiate the base using the Type with specific configuration instance. The work method does not necessarily require a parameter. See my updated post